# Tezbox and Ledger Problem

Tags: ledger

Here is my problem.
I have Ledger Nano S installed with my Tezbox wallet.
But, the Ledger doesn't recognize the wallet hash when I try to add an account.
Nor can I send any coins out of the wallet.
Can anyone help me?
Thank you
Francis
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
This Tezbox wallet has Ledger Nano S using the Brave Browser.
The first problem I see is this. "This account hasn't been revealed yet."
What does that mean?

When I try to add an account. The wallet says to make sure that there is 
a balance in the wallet.
I can easily see that many Tezos coins are in the balance and in the wallet. 
I sent them there from an exchange.
Why doesn't the wallet see what is in it?
I can clearly see the transactions of the coins.

Finally, when I try to send. The address box doesn't allow for a right click option when I try to paste in the receiving address.
When I add the receiving address manually. The Ledger Nano doesn't recognize the operation, (hash?) and stops the transaction.
If anyone can help me. I sure would appreciate it.
I am guessing the Brave Browser could be some of the problem.
I just don't know.
Thank you
Francis

Comment: hi, welcome to Tezos Stack Exchange! Could you please provide more details about the error you face. Please add actual error msg or relevant screenshot etc... You can also indicate what is your environment. tx

Comment: Prefer text to screenshots. You can also obfuscate sensitive details, if you know which details are sensitive...